# UPDATE table values (SET min value) on the columns with the same id

Tags: mysql

```
id  |  price
100 |  12.5
101 |  15.8
100 |  20.8
99  |  45.2
101 |  11.7
79  |  10.4
100 |  14.7
101 |  18.8
```

I am searching a solution for this problem.

I want a result like this using MySQL UPDATE command ...

```
id  |  price
100 |  12.5
101 |  11.7
100 |  12.5
99  |  45.2
101 |  11.7
79  |  10.4
100 |  12.5
101 |  11.7
```

Any solutions please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try an update join to a subquery which finds the minimum price for each `id` group:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MIN(price) AS min_price
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.price = t2.min_price;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE t

 SET    t.Price= o.MinPrice

FROM   yourTable t

INNER JOIN (select id , min(price) MinPrice from yourTable group by id ) o ON o.id= t.id
```

Comment: Not sure, why it was down-voted. But i suggest to add some description of the solution so that it would be easier for people to understand approach.

Comment: does not compile in MySQL 5.6

Comment: see the first answer, the join is after the update statement, mssql and mysql must but different

Answer (score -1):

Try Simple subquery which will update the values of table

```
update myTable t1, 
(select * from (select * from myTable order by price) x group by id) t2 
set t1.price = t2.price where t1.id = t2.id;
```

Before execution of query, data is like:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | price |
+------+-------+
|  100 |  12.5 |
|  101 |  15.8 |
|  100 |  20.8 |
|   90 |  45.2 |  
|  101 |  11.7 |
|   79 |  10.4 |
|  100 |  14.7 |
|  101 |  18.8 |
+------+-------+
```

After execution:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | price |
+------+-------+
|  100 |  12.5 |
|  101 |  11.7 |
|  100 |  12.5 |
|   90 |  45.2 |
|  101 |  11.7 |
|   79 |  10.4 |
|  100 |  12.5 |
|  101 |  11.7 |
+------+-------+
```